# HTML table td width different with same colspan

Tags: html, css

below is my experimental code,

I'm now confusing why the two cells at first row have different width when I was trying to inspect them.

https://jsfiddle.net/rbx1219/43j6obxt/3/

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <div class='big'>

        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <div class='big'>

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[td width unexpected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EipRe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `display: inline-block;` to prevent the element from filling the width.

Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=control